# Jenkins: Emails not being sent from email-ext

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, email-ext

I'm trying to send emails from Jenkins using the groovy script. My problem is that emails are going to some distribution lists while they're not going to other DLs. Here is a code snippet:

```
  emailext (
      subject: subject,
      body: content,
      to: 'a.b@x.com, c.d@x.com, #d.e@y.com, #f.g@y.com'
    )
```

The emails are being sent to the IDs `a.b@x.com, c.d@x.com, #d.e@y.com` but no one in `#f.g@y.com` gets the email.

I'm sure there's no spelling mistake or typo in my to list as when i open the email on outlook, i'm able to expand the `#f.g@y.com` to see all the members.

What am i missing out on?

Comment: instead of "," do the separation between emails with ";"

Comment: @eranmeiri, i tried this and it didn't work. I'm seeing the same issue. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Now , we have two possible issues , 1. jenkins issue with email sending 2. groovy script 
For testing point 1 , goto manage jenkins , configure ( and search for Test configuration by sending test e-mail) and try sending a test email to that dl, if that works , then we are down to groovy script , for that try space instead of comma (, )